# Previewing my design in browser makes it larger

Tags: adobe-fireworks, browser

I haven't been able to find the answer to this which is really frustrating. My zoom level on both chrome and firefox are 100 . My zoom level in adobe fireworks on the same machine is also 100. For some reason the design i create in adobe fireworks which is sharp and smaller is quite a bit larger and more fuzzy in both firefox and chrome. Why is this and how do i fix it? This must be a common problem but very strange.

Thanks allot for your help.

Comment: Using a retina screen?

Comment: What's the file resolution? I imagine if it's a higher resolution it may be much bigger on any display/browser. Also, have not had any experience with fireworks so i'm sorry if that's irrelevant.

Comment: Im using a external moniter for a laptop (windows pc). What really seems to be the issue is that my browser is responding to my overall laptop display settings of 125% magnification.I think thats a fairly common setting on windows so im wondering how to negate it through code in my CSS/Javscript/html.

Comment: You need to consider the resolution of each display at an OS level. If you are designing at native pixels (one literal pixel per pixel), and have artificial resolution on your laptop screen to make things look bigger, you're mismatched.

Answer (score -1):

this is due to the resolution of the system u r using.  FOr example, if u r using 1800px resolution then u found ur screen would become small and it loooks much better in chrome and firefox.

Comment: What Luciano said: the Asker also wants to fix the issue. Thanks for adding your solution!